# Sending request to NetSuite ERP using Spring web client having Oauth1 authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, netsuite, spring-webclient, oauth-1.0a

I need to migrate a legacy NetSuite ERP job using Springboot. The clients are using OAUTH1 authentication so I couldn't find a straightforward way to send requests using Spring WebClient or Webflux. Finally ended up using https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava for sending requests.
Is there any better way to handle this?

When I searched there are a lot of options to send requests having OAUTH1 authentication using Spring web flux. Never find anything similar to that having Oauth1 authentication.